# Accessing files from "shared/transfers" using a URI does not work for a WP8 app anymore

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8

I have a WP7 application that I run successfully on both WP7 and WP8 devices. In the app I download audio files using the `BackgroundFileTransfer` service and store the files to the `shared/transfers` folder. I then create `AudioTrack`s by giving a URI to the downloaded file locations.

```cs
        Uri episodeLocation;
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(" *** Creating track, file exists: " + iso.FileExists("shared/transfers/song.mp3"));
            }
            episodeLocation = new Uri("shared/transfers/song.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
        } catch(Exception) {
            return null;
        }

        return new AudioTrack(episodeLocation,
                        "Track name",
                        "Album name",
                        "",
                        new Uri("/path/to/logo", UriKind.Relative));
```

**This works great on both Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 devices** - audio player is able to play the track just fine. The debug output prints `True` as the result for the test if file exists.

I've now converted the application in Visual Studio 2012 to be a Windows Phone 8 application. If I now run the application in Windows Phone 8, I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` external exception from the player. Also in the converted version the debug output prints `True` when checking if the file exists.

**I only converted the app from a WP7 to WP8 app** and I cannot refer to files in `shared/transfers` any more.

Why?

What's the proper way to do this?

I already tried referring to the files by using the URI `isostore:/shared/transfers/song.mp3` but that didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: In fact, it seems moving the audio files to any other directory or even the root directory yields the same result: FileExists() returns true, but Audio player throws FileNotFound exception.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was that I now created a completely new and empty WP8 project and then I copied over all the old code from the WP7 project to this new WP8 project and I then rebuilt the solution. I did no code modifications whatsoever from the version that I had when I wrote this post, I converted from a WP7 project to an WP8 and that has issues.

**Audio player is again able to play the audio files.**

So an advice to anyone with WP7 projects: Do not convert them in Visual Studio to WP8 projects as wierd things can happen.

Comment: Did you compare converted .csproj with newly created one? What were the differences?

Comment: I did not compare. I don't have time to fix Microsoft's bugs.

Comment: Nobody's talking about fixing bugs, that's just a curiosity :) Nevermind

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I fink I've found it - in my case the problem is that my BackgroundDowload needs an Uri file location, I create Uri like this:

```
fileName = "shared/transfers/my filename.txt";
fileName = Uri.EscapeUriString(fileName);
Uri fileUri = new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative);
```

With or without second line of the code above, file is saved to a location of escaped string format. It seems to be like this, becouse it's provided as Uri.
The file is downloaded and as you mentioned, it's created and exists as FileExists() shows.
I've my 'escaped' fileName and when I want to (for example) play an audio I do something like this:

```
return new AudioTrack(new Uri(Uri.EscapedUriString(fileName), UriKind.Relative), title ....);
```

Hope it helps you as it works for me.

Comment: In my case I don't have white space in my file names, so our cases clearly differ.

Comment: White space was only example here. Give it a try, and also check what string[] str = ISF.GetFileNames("/shared/transfers/"); returns. If you don't have any special characters in **returned filenames (str)** then I've no idea (for now) what can solve your problem.